# Why Axios abort API request not working in react and nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have MERN stack application and I want to cancel an API request when the back button is pressed.

```
     useEffect(()=>{
     const controller = new AbortController();

     const fetchSingleUser = async () =>{
     const response = await axios.get(`/users/singleUser/${path}`,  {
     signal: controller.signal})

  
      setUser(response.data)


     }


  fetchSingleUser()

 return function cancel() {
  console.log('abort')
  controller.abort()
}
 
  

}, [path])
```

When I opened this page and hit the browser back button to go back to another page, I checked network and saw that the API request was running on the background until it completes. It should have canceled the request.

Comment: Is "abort" being logged to the console? Have you tried throtteling your network to see if the request maybe is just finished before you hit the back button?

Comment: Yes, the abort is loggged// And I am using slow 3G on the network tab

Comment: And the request actually doesn't complete immediately, it gets completed after few minutes, after another page has finished loading

Comment: I think there is an issue. I used the axios.CancelToken.source() which axios said is depreciated, and it is working. I think the new AbortController() proper usage in react is the issue. I have checked online and I can see that people are also struggling with how to properly used. I am sticking with the depreciated version except I see how to properly use the new method.

Comment: Yes I have also had issues with AbortController in the past. One thing to look out for is that an instance of an AbortController can only be used once. Maybe this controller in the cleanup closure is different from the one attached to the axios request?

Comment: It is same. Both coming from the controller variable at the top level.